# Calculate logarithm function in a raster in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

How do I calculate a logarithm function in a raster in R?

Something like the below code snippet
    `t = log(3-raster1/raster2-raster1,rasterBase)`
where `rasterBase` is the raster using as a base of logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always provide some example data/code:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1 <- setValues(r, 1000)
r2 <- setValues(r,  1:100)
```

A solution:

```
x <- overlay(r1, r2, fun=function(x, y) log(x, y))
x
```

An alternative:

```
s <- stack(r1, r2)
y <- calc(s, fun=function(x) log(x[1], x[2]))
```

For completeness sake, note that for a fixed base, e.g. 10, you can do

```
x <- log(r1, 10)
```